# Phaser collision: execute function one time

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I have a little problem in the collisions while using [Phaser API](http://docs.phaser.io/).

I have this code:

```
game.physics.arcade.collide(sprite1, sprite2, this.collision, null, this);

   collsion: function(){
      //Play a sound;
   }
```

The problem here is when the two sprites collide the sound keeps playing.  It only stops when they are not colliding.  But I want to play the sound just the one time.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited** after testing myself.

Try the **overlap**:

```
create : function() {
...
this.timeDelay = 0;
}

game.physics.arcade.overlap(sprite1, sprite2, this.overlap, null, this);

overlap: function(){
    if (game.time.now > this.timeDelay){
                game.sound.play("sound");
                // wait 1 second
                timeDelay = game.time.now + 1000
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyway i've found how, i have made a variable that check if the function is executed or not:

   executed = false;

   game.physics.arcade.collide(sprite1, sprite2, this.collision,       null, this); 

collision: function(){
if (!executed) {
      executed = true;
      //Play the sound
   }

Comment: @AbdellahSabiri I tried your way but still got the problem. So I decided to delay it. I edited my answer.